# Can I map an import component and its children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a component, import other components, in these components other components, and so on. Is it possible to somehow recognize them all and make something like a tree.

Comment: What do you mean by recognize them all?

Comment: No, there doesn't seem to be any tools that can do so.

Comment: Hmmmm what's your use case tho?

Comment: @IamL This is for preloading chunks, before going to a page.

Comment: @VladimirGolub Why not use Lazy loading that react uses? That's what it does: check this out: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no javascript support or any tool that does this.
But you can improve circular dependencies in javascript using 'circular-dependency-plugin'.
Please find below article on same

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/06/25/circular-dependencies-javascript/